# issue with multiple radio button tags in same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A user has the ability to answer a set of question. Now some are text, whilst others are radio buttons.

The issue I'm running into is that the radio buttons that are populated for each question, currently seem to belong to the same group. So for instance, if I have 2 questions that require you to answer with a radio button, then you can only select one of them because the buttons are connected.

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this issue, here's my view:

```
  <% if question.text_based? %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'questions[][reply]', nil, class: 'form-control', "required" => true, rows: 2 %>
  <% else %>

    <% (question.min_number_range..question.max_number_range).each do |question_value| %>
      <%= label_tag 'questions[][reply]', class: 'question-value-label' do %>
        <%= question_value %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'questions[][reply]', "#{question_value}" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

HTML output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="questions[][id]" id="questions__id" value="5" />
<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[][reply]" id="questions__reply_1" value="1" />
</label>          
<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[][reply]" id="questions__reply_2" value="2" />
</label>          

<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[][reply]" id="questions__reply_3" value="3" />
    </label> 
</label> 

<input type="hidden" name="questions[][id]" id="questions__id" value="6" />
<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[][reply]" id="questions__reply_1" value="1" />
</label>          
<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[][reply]" id="questions__reply_2" value="2" />
</label>
```

and my controller code:

```
  def create
    @questions = current_user.questions
    params[:questions].map do |question|
      current_user.answers.create(
        question_id: question[:id],
        reply:       question[:reply],
        week_number: Time.zone.now.strftime('%V')
      )
    end
    redirect_to answers_path
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to number your `questions`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="questions[0][id]" id="questions__id" value="5" />
<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[0][reply]" id="questions__reply_1" value="1" />
</label>          
<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[0][reply]" id="questions__reply_2" value="2" />
</label>          

<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[0][reply]" id="questions__reply_3" value="3" />
    </label> 
</label> 

<input type="hidden" name="questions[1][id]" id="questions__id" value="6" />
<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[1][reply]" id="questions__reply_1" value="1" />
</label>          
<label class="question-value-label" for="questions__reply">
   <input type="radio" name="questions[1][reply]" id="questions__reply_2" value="2" />
</label>
```

Comment: that makes sense, however I'm unable to make it work with my current code, ive updated with my controller code